# Issue while installing Apache in linux

Tags: linux, apache2, apache

I know there are similar questions out there but I haven't found the exact solution for this problem.
Installing Apache, downloaded **httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz** and followed the following installation procedure:

```
cp httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz /usr/local/src

cd /usr/local/src

gunzip httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz

tar -xvf httpd-2.4.3.tar

rm -f httpd-2.4.3.tar

cd httpd-2.4.3

export CFLAGS=-O2

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all

make

make install

cd /usr/local/apache2/bin

./apachectl start
```

Now, instead of starting any said service m facing following error:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd)
```

I have also downloaded and installed **glibc-2.14.1-14.27.1.x86_64.rpm** and have also checked manually that the library file **libc.so.6** is present in the location **/lib64**.

Can any1 help me regarding this where m missing  ?
Thanks in advance m new to this.

Comment: It seems like a version conflict? What is the glibc version you are having. Also which is the distro you are using?

Comment: But what is your distro example Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian etc?

Comment: M having its 2.16 version with SUSE version 11 distribution.

Comment: If installing from source is not important, try installing from your package manager (Yast, I think) that will resolve dependencies and version requirements.

Comment: via Yast interface m getting the same error, just tried this also.